# How to debug and fix a failure of <C-]> to jump to a tag in vim over PuTTY, even though :tag <tagname> works?

Tags: vim, exuberant-ctags

I recently generated tags for my project using Exuberant Ctags following *approach 4* at: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/faq.html#15.

After this, I have been able to use the tags, tag and stags command to jump to tags. However, Ctrl + ] i.e. `<C-]>` does not jump to a tag when pressed.

I read through some similar questions and found that the following might be relevant:

```
:verbose setlocal iskeyword?
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,#
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/vim.vim
```

And

```
:map <C-]>
No mapping found
```

My Ctrl and ] keys are working fine. I'm able to type the square brace, and I'm also able to use commands like Ctrl + W h/j/k/l to switch between vim splits.

I have checked inside and outside of screen, and checked my .vimrc and .bashrc as well. My .vimrc is at: http://pastebin.com/GkF416SY

Unfortunately, I remain clueless as to whether Ctrl + ] is getting eaten by some program (PuTTY/bash?) or if there is some other issue. I would really appreciate help in fixing this issue. I'd be happy to provide any further information.

**EDIT:** I'm using a COLEMAK layout with an ordinary keyboard. The [ key is immediately to the left of Enter.

**EDIT 2:**

- I still have the same problem with the staffanc/cscopemaps.vim plugin      turned off and cleaned with PluginClean.
- I've ensured that cscopetag is not set by using 'set cscopetag&' within the session. It still did not help.
- I tried Ctrl + W } -> this opens the preview window with the tag in it. The problem keeps getting weirder.

**EDIT 3:**
Following @gregory's advice, remapping  to  worked. Interestingly enough, mapping  to  and pressing Alt + ] doesn't work!

Oddly, Alt + \, Alt + / also don't work while remapping. One side's Alt key is sending in the character directly, so I'm forced to use Right Alt.

**EDIT 4:** 
I found the following in the list of mapped keys:

```
o  [%          * v:<C-U>call <SNR>13_MultiMatch("bW", "o") <CR>
v  [%            <Esc>[%m'gv``
n  [%          * :<C-U>call <SNR>13_MultiMatch("bW", "n") <CR>
o  ]%          * v:<C-U>call <SNR>13_MultiMatch("W",  "o") <CR>
v  ]%            <Esc>]%m'gv``
n  ]%          * :<C-U>call <SNR>13_MultiMatch("W",  "n") <CR>
```

I'm not sure, but this may be the cause of the problem. Could you please explain the use of the '%' character here? I took a quick look, but I haven't been able to track it down yet.

Comment: is cscopetag set? that uses ctrl-], perhaps a conflict? Have you tried skipping your steffanc/cscopemaps.vim to see if that's causing an issue?

Comment: @gregory I just tried disabling steffanc/cscopemaps; it doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue. I also used set cscopetag&, so that set cscopetag? outputs nocscopetag. I still have the same issue.

Comment: In bash, do you have .inputrc with a C-] mapping?

Comment: @gregory ~/.inputrc and /root/.inputrc don't exist. Should I check any other places?

Comment: No, that rules that out.  Ok, how about troubleshooting this: you could try remapping C-] to something else to see if any keystroke will work? For example: map <C-A> <C-]>

Comment: I tried mapping <M-a> to <C-]> and that instantly fixed my issue. I'm super curious now: what is eating my <C-]>, I wonder?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, with gvim and neovim in the windows console. I swap back to qwerty to hit c-[. Should be the same on colemak, but for whatever reason isn't. Using `c-v`, in qwerty I get `^[` and in colemak I get nothing, even in gvim. It just doesn't send the key combo.

Answer (score 1):

On my French AZERTY keyboard, if want want to hit `CTRL+]`, I have to remember where it's placed on a US/QWERTY keyboard. Then, I hit CTRL + this key.

IOW, as I never remember where those keys are depending on the keyboard used, I've mapped `CTRL+]` to something I can remember: `<M-Down>`.

Comment: It's `<C-$>`. Easy.

Comment: @romainl, I tried out C-Shift-+ and C-shift-$ and C-+ and C-$. None of them worked. I do appreciate your comment: I'll bet that this will save many people struggling with AZERTY.

Comment: @Luc Hermite, you have the tag jumps mapped to Meta + Down arrow? Isn't that pretty difficult to press while keeping your hand on the home row? I'm thinking that maybe M-] might be easier. I haven't ever remapped keys before, so I'll try reading up on the wiki. If it is okay, I'll reach out if I run into trouble with remapping.

Comment: @batbrat, that comment was only directed at Luc Hermitte (and possible AZERTY-using passerbys).

Comment: @batbrat, I'm not a touch typist, nor an fundamentalist: I really don't care about restricting myself to 55 keys. My keyboard has 102 keys at least and I use most of them. Even if this means I must move my hands. 15years or so ago I found meta+down easier to remember (which is what is the more important), now I stick with it.

Comment: Also, note that mapping meta/alt is complex in pure terminal-vim -- that's one of the main the reasons why I use gvim. And what you must understand is: look for an image/photo of an US/QWERTY keyboard on the net, and find the key on your keyboard which replaces `]` on the other one. Most likely, the keybinding you're looking for is CTRL + this key.

Comment: @LucHermitte I can certainly understand what you mean about remembering being more important. As for gvim, that's not an option for me. The ] key is at the same position in both layouts. That said, I will double check as you suggested. :)

Comment: @batbrat. If the key is at the same position in both layouts, then, I have no idea where to look for.